# C++builder 10.3 исчезли элементы подменю file-new

Tags: c++builder

C++builder 10.3 исчезли элементы подменю file-new. Остался только Other и Customize. Как можно восстанавливать остальных элементов меню, например, Windows VCL application?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: скорее всего либо недоустановились пакеты, либо кто то в настройках выключил их. Вспоминайте, что делали последнее время